# how to add input fields dynamically in angularjs on button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make a simple example in which an input field and a button field each time a user clicks on button.

How can I get the text of the input field when the new button, which is present along with input field, is clicked?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNLGzx

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic']);
app.controller('cntr',function($scope){
     $scope.addfield=function(){
       alert("how to add input field dyanmically")
     }

})
```

I don't know how to do this; in jQuery we can use the append function, like so

```
$('.addcontend').append('<input \> <button>get input value</button>')
```

How can I acheive this using angularjs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you can do is to use an array to represent the inputs then loop through the array and render it like

```
<div class="addcontend">
  <div ng-repeat="item in inputs">
    <input ng-model="item.value"/> <button ng-click='addfield()'>get input value</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

then

```
  $scope.inputs = [];
  $scope.addfield=function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({})
  }
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVNoYP)

Comment: thanks for answer but how to get value of input field which is generated dynamically from dynamically generated button

Comment: How do you want the value?

Comment: from dynamically button click

Comment: How does angular make to differentiate each item.value from the rest? I don't understand this care to explain a little more please?